# When using NSIS, how do I create an uninstaller with custom pages?

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

I would like to have an uninstaller with custom NS pages. How do I do that with NSIS?

Answer (score 6):

```
Function un.mypageCreate
;call nsDialogs or InstallOptions functions here
FunctionEnd

UninstPage custom un.mypageCreate
```

Comment: The function needs to be called "un.mypageCreate". See Rover's (more correct) answer. Otherwise the compiler won't be able to resolve the function.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
UninstPage custom un.mypage

Function un.mypage
    ;func body here
FunctionEnd
```

"un." is required for uninstall functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Function has to begin with un. (e.g. "un.myPageCreate") though I'm not sure that is the problem the error message is referring to.