# Can I have optional sections in an NSIS UNinstaller?

Tags: nsis

When building my installer, I can let the user choose which sections to install by calling

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
```

How can I provide similar functionality in the uninstaller?

I know how to make the sections themselves (thanks to the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365268/when-using-nsis-how-do-i-create-an-uninstaller-with-custom-pages)). I just don't know how to let the user choose which of these sections to uninstall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do the same things as in the installer, you just need the correct uninstaller prefix:

[`MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html)

and

```
Section /o un.optional
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that. I wasn't sure where it belonged in the script. I stuck that line right after the MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS line and that does the trick. Thanks!